# Tenho um panel no aspx, mas dá erro no code behind(Web Form)

Tags: c#

Peguei um projeto em aspx para manter e tenho isso na página aspx

`<asp:Panel ID="painelTeste" runat="server">`

e no code behind dá erro

> O nome painelTeste não existe no contexto atual.

O que devo fazer?

**EDit1**

meu contexto no code behind.

```
if (DateTime.Now < dataFaturamento)
{
    painelTeste .Visible = false;
}
else
{
    painelTeste .Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Pode postar o trecho do code behind onde dá o erro?

Comment: Se faço isso, some o erro: `Panel painelTeste = this.FindControl("painelTeste") as Panel;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente esse panel foi criado quando o projeto estava sendo executado, com isso não foi gerado a referência para ele no arquivo `NomeDaSuaPagina.aspx.designer.cs`.

Precisa ser um refêrencia parecida com isso no designer da página:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel painelTeste;
```

Tente adicionar essa referência manualmente, caso não funcione apague o controle, salve o projeto, reinicie o Visual Studio e escreva o controle novamente que o designer será complementado corretamente.